# DateTime::diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, bool given

Tags: php, datetime, parameters, diff

Every `$firstTransaction` is different, but comes is essentially just an array of dates generated by  `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time())` and the first is used.

This code has worked flawlessly before, but I just moved hosting providers and this one seems to be giving me trouble even though the PHP version is exactly the same as the last host.

```
$start_date = new DateTime();
$ts1 = $start_date->createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $firstTransaction[0]);
$ts2 = new DateTime('now');
                
$diff = $ts2->diff($ts1);
```

The error in question:

```
DateTime::diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, bool given
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am at a total loss.

EDIT: The exact date in question was:

```
$firstTransaction[0] = '2023-01-03 00:55:15';
```

Comment: As per https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php, createFromFormat will return false (a bool!) if it fails. So evidently, it failed to parse the date using the format you specified, hence why `$ts1` ended up as a bool. Please provide an example of the data contained within `$firstTransaction[0]`, so we can see what format it's actually in (assuming it's actually a date at all)

Comment: The exact date I received this error to is: $firstTransaction = '2023-01-03 00:55:15';

Comment: Thanks. Based on that, there should be no problem with your code - demo: https://3v4l.org/qhAJX . Are you perhaps doing this repeatedly on different data items (e.g. in a loop or something)? Maybe it's failing on a different value than that?

Comment: which is why I'm so confused. this worked flawlessly on multiple hosting providers. This one just seems to have an issue here and unfortunately, this section of code influences a lot.

Comment: Well, we can't easily help you currently as we don't have a reproducible example of the problem. The code seems to work. You'll need to debug in more detail in the problem environment. Possibly something is wrong with the data, that seems to be the most likely explanation, but you so far haven't provided any data from that environment which would cause an issue.

Comment: Works for me with a small change:: https://3v4l.org/a8CKV

Comment: @jspit I think that change fixed it... what's weird was that the code was working, got the correct results from the datetime code I included and was fine. it just threw an error, but now nothing. changing it to Datetime::etc was all it wanted... so bizarre, but thank you!